# Views url paths not using proper url on localhost

Tags: views

When running site on localhost and using field rewrite I construct a link like this for example

```
<a href="/[uid]/addresses/shipping/default/[profile_id_1]">Set as default</a>
```

I get a path that is not proper. Something like this

```
http://localhost/1/addresses/shipping/default/284
```

and it is missing a site part in url and should be like

```
http://localhost/MY-SITE/1/addresses/shipping/default/284
```

I have set a $base_url in settings.php but doesnt help. When I put site online this works fine, but what should I do for localhost?

Comment: Have you modified your RewriteBase in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter your .htaccess file:

```
# Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
# VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
# For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
# modify the following line:
# RewriteBase /drupal
```

Comment: I made this now, restarted cache and localhost just in case but still nothing :( Still the url is without the base.  Just localhost/user/.... and should be
localhost/my-base/user...

Comment: Think it might be the way you're constructing your URLs in Views, change the options to:

1. Under Rewrite the output of this field change to just "Set as default"
2. Under Output this field as a link change to [uid]/addresses/shipping/default/[profile_id_1]

Comment: Problem is that I need to have it in "Rewrite the output of this field" as I have combo of HTML, and the other problem is why isn't views using proper path in this case?

Comment: Your method is not passing through the l function and will always have the wrong path what additional HTML do you need

Comment: Makes sense, thanx